# How to include item fields in group select linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a linq select. In the select I would like to have the components fields. How can I get the component fields? In my select I am grouping by `componentId` but I would like to include the component fields. For example `component.Name`. Thank you for your help.

```
        var inventories = from inventory in _context.Inventories
                          join component in _context.Components on inventory.ComponentId equals component.ComponentId
                          join location in _context.ComponentLocations on inventory.LocationId equals location.LocationId
                          group inventory by new { inventory.ComponentId } into i
                          select new
                          {
                              i.Key.ComponentId,
                          };
```

Comment: Add component fields to grouping key or join to components after grouping.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Or include in grouping: `group new { inventory, component } by `

Comment: If `_context` is a DbContext, you're using it the wrong way. You shouldn't have to use any JOINs, it's the ORM's job to generate any necessary JOINs from the relations between objects. You won't be able to create a `group by` that doesn't result in a valid SQL GROUP BY clause either. This means that you either have to use any properties as group keys or as aggregates

Comment: @NetMage I am using EF 6.x and  mysql

Comment: In any case you need to remove all those JOINs. Depending on what you want to group and select, you don't have to start from Inventories. If each `Component` has a single `Inventory`, accessing `Component.Inventory.SomeField` would generate the necessary JOINs. The same with ComponentLocations. You could group directly by Component ID for example and EF would create the JOINs necessary to include any Inventory or Location fields needed